# How do I word wrap in timevis?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, plot, gantt-chart

I've made a gantt chart with `timevis` in `R`. Some of the bars in my gantt chart have quite long text in, so anything after about the 10th word is cut off. Is there a way to wrap the words into second or third lines?

```
gantt <- structure(list(group = c("How FAN1 stabilises repeats", "How FAN1 stabilises repeats"
), content = c("CRISPR nuclease and SPYF", "Effect of FAN1 SPAA and MIM mutant on MLH1 binding, ICL repair and CAG instability"
), start = structure(c(1662516351.36, 1662516351.36), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                               "POSIXt")), end = structure(c(1677242989.44, 1677242989.44), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                                                                     "POSIXt")), style = c("color: white; background-color: maroon;font-size:9px;word-break: break-all;", 
                                                                                                                                                                                           "color: white; background-color: maroon;font-size:9px;word-break: break-all;"
                                                                                                                                                                     ), type = c("range", "range")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "tbl", "data.frame"))    


groups <- data.frame(id = unique(gantt$group),
                     content = unique(gantt$group),
                     style = "font-weight: bold; font-size:10px")

timevis(data = gantt, groups = groups,
        options = list(editable = TRUE, height = "600px"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stringr::str_wrap` to nicely wrap the text to the desired maximum width. It works by inserting newline characters which won't work in this context though, so you'll need to substitute these with `<br>`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

gantt %>%
  mutate(content = gsub("\n", "<br>", str_wrap(content, 30))) %>%
  timevis(groups = groups, options = list(editable = TRUE, height = "600px"))
```

[image]